How to prove that a strictly increasing sequence of whole numbers approaches infinity?

Prove that if $(a_n)$ is a strictly increasing sequence ($a_{n+1}> a_n$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$), and $a_n \in \mathbb{Z}$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, then $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} a_n = \infty$.

The statement seems relatively obvious but I'm not sure how to go about proving it.

Hint: Suppose you have an arbitrary value $N$ (like you do when proving a limit to infinity), and the first value of your sequence is $k=a_0$; what is the minimum value of $a_{N-k}$?

By induction $a_n\geq n-1+a_1.$ Well, it would be my first attempt.

Try to prove that for any $n \in \mathbb N$ that $a_n \ge a_0 + n$.  Then..... for any $M \in \mathbb R$ let $N > M-a_0$ and the result follows directly for the definition of "$\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n = 0$"

Also If $a_{n+1} > a_n$ and $a_{n+1}, a_n \in \mathbb Z$ then $a_{n+1} -a_n > 0$ and $a_{n+1} -a_n \in \mathbb Z$ so .... $a_{n+1} -a_n$ is an integer larger than $0$.  What is the smallest integer larger than $0$.  So $a_{n+1} - a_n \ge 1$.

ANd a third hint.   Obviously not all strictly increasing sequence tend to infinity (ex.  $\lim (1-\frac 1{2^n}) = 1$).  So what difference would the sequence consisting of only integers imply. .... (Answer:  The difference between terms is always at least $1$.)

What I love about math is that there are always so many way to do things.  Note:  $a_n - a_0 = (a_n-a_{n-1}) + (a_{n-1} - a_{n-2}) + (a_{n-2}-a_{n-3}) + .... +(a_2 -a_1) + (a_1-a_0) \ge 1+1+1+..... +1+1$.  Archimedian principal anyone?

Thanks everyone! Proved it by induction using Steen82's method (and from there concluded that the limit must also equal infinity). The other comments also brought some great insight, so thank you all!

Let $N \in \mathbb{Z}$ be arbitrary. We need to show that there is some $n_N \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ such that $a_n > N$ for each $n > n_N$.
Consider the following statement:

For any $k \ge j$ where $j, k \in \mathbb{Z}^+$, we have that $a_k > a_j + k - j - 1$.

We can prove it by induction. Let $j \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ be arbitrary. As a base case, consider $k = j$. We have trivially that $a_k = a_j > a_j - 1$. Now, suppose that the statement holds for some $k \ge j$. By the hypothesis that $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{Z}^+}$ is a strictly increasing sequence in $\mathbb{Z}$, we have that $a_{k + 1} \ge a_k + 1$, and by the inductive hypothesis, $a_k > a_j + k - j - 1$. These together imply
$$a_{k + 1} > (a_j + k - j - 1) + 1 = a_j + (k + 1) - j - 1$$
as desired.
With the statement above in place, the rest of the proof is easy. If $a_1 \ge N$, then just choose $n_N = 1$; every element in the sequence after the first will exceed $N$. Otherwise, select $n_N = N - a_1 + 2 \in \mathbb{Z}^+$. For any $n > n_N$, the statement above with $k = n$ and $j = 1$ shows that
$$a_n > a_1 + n - 1 - 1 > a_1 + n_N - 2 = a_1 + (N - a_1 + 2) - 2 = N$$
as desired.

Here is a non induction proof.
If $a_n$ is strictly increasing, i.e. $a_{n}\ge a_{n-1}+1,$ then subtracting $n$ implies that  $b_n:=a_n-n$ is non decreasing. Therefore $b_n\ge b_1$ which is equivalent to $a_n-n\ge a_1-1.$ Thus $a_n\ge n+(a_1-1),$ which implies $a_n\to\infty.$
